# Bluetooth Low Energy APP works on Nexus but not with others

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm programming an app for a connected device (Nordic BLE).

I used the accelerator bluetooth sample (bluetooth SIG).

The app detects well my object on a LG NEXUS 5 but not on my other Acer Liquid Z200 nor on my Wiko GOA.

These phones normally supports BLE.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Nicolas

Here the paste of the code :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = null;
    private boolean mScanning = false;
    private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    private ListAdapter mLeDeviceListAdapter;

    private static final long SCAN_TIMEOUT = 5000;

    static class ViewHolder {
        public TextView text;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.d("debug", ".");
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Initializes Bluetooth adapter.
        final BluetoothManager bluetoothManager = (BluetoothManager) getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
        mBluetoothAdapter = bluetoothManager.getAdapter();

        mLeDeviceListAdapter = new ListAdapter();

        ((ListView) this.findViewById(R.id.deviceList))
                .setAdapter(mLeDeviceListAdapter);
    }

    public void onScan(View view) {
        // check bluetooth is available on on
        if (mBluetoothAdapter == null || !mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(
                    BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivity(enableBtIntent);
            return;
        }

        scanLeDevice(!mScanning);
    }

    private void setScanState(boolean value) {
        mScanning = value;
        setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(value);
        ((Button) this.findViewById(R.id.scanButton)).setText(value ? "Stop"
                : "Scan");
    }

    private void scanLeDevice(final boolean enable) {
        if (enable) {
            // scan for SCAN_TIMEOUT
            mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    setScanState(false);
                    mBluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
                }
            }, SCAN_TIMEOUT);

            setScanState(true);
            mLeDeviceListAdapter.clear();
            mLeDeviceListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            UUID[] uuids = new UUID[1];
            uuids[0] = UUID.fromString("6E400001-B5A3-F393-E0A9-E50E24DCCA9K");
            mBluetoothAdapter.startLeScan( uuids, mLeScanCallback);
        } else {
            setScanState(false);
            mBluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
        }
    }

    // Device scan callback.
    private BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback mLeScanCallback = new BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onLeScan(final BluetoothDevice device, int rssi,
                byte[] scanRecord) {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                Log.d("debug", "device found");//DOES NOT APPEND ON ACER AND WIKO   
                }
            });
        }
    };
```

Comment: what happens when it fails to work?  Anything in the log? What have you tried to do to debug it?

Comment: Nothing in the log. Nothing appends. I tried an app for bluetooth (no BLE) and it works well. It looks like only nexus is able to detect it whereas the official apps for bluetooth devices found my device.